# Extract all statistic of a process from /proc just before the process exit (Linux)

Tags: linux, kernel, proc

I need to get some statistic(io, network) of a process during its lifetime. Is there anyway to get those information from /proc just before the process exit ? Linux Kernel API ?

Comment: Maybe you can use GNU's time function (`/usr/bin/time`) which can output lots of statistic. You can look at its source code to see how it works.

Answer (score 3):

#### `wait4()` and `struct rusage`

A simple way to gather some statistics after *child* process termination is [`wait4(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) syscall, which can fill [`rusage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) struct.

---

#### `ptrace()`

If it's not enough, you can probably use [`ptrace(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) to stop a process just before its termination:

> **PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT** (since Linux 2.5.60)
>
> Stop the tracee at exit.  A `waitpid(2)` by the tracer
>   will return a status value such that
>
> ```
> status>>8 == (SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_EXIT<<8))
> ```
>
> The tracee's exit status can be retrieved with
>   `PTRACE_GETEVENTMSG`.
>
> The tracee is stopped early during process exit, when
>   registers are still available, allowing the tracer to
>   see where the exit occurred, whereas the normal exit
>   notification is done after the process is finished
>   exiting.  Even though context is available, the tracer
>   cannot prevent the exit from happening at this point.

When [`waitpid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) will report that process is going to terminate and stopped, you can gather statistics from `/proc`, but I didn't try this.

---

#### `KProbes`

The most generic solution I know is [`KProbes`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) and derivatives. You can probably use DTrace or SystemTap to trap `sys_exit()` and gather statistics.

Comment: Thx. But I don't know the pid of the process which are going to exit. So I want to trace all the process when they exit

Comment: @ChrisLiu, then maybe take a look at KProbes. I think they allow what you need.

Comment: Thanks for ur solution. I am looking on KProbes and place a Probe on `do_exit`