# Is it possible to measure cumulative IO wait time of a Linux process?

Tags: linux, performance, io, profiling

Which C API can I use to get **total disk IO wait time** (absolute value) for the exiting child process on Linux? *E.g. process with PID 1234 was running for 10 seconds and 3 seconds it was waiting for IO operations to complete.*

**Background:**
I am trying to find out how much the slowness of disks contributed to the slowness of the application. In other words: *how long does the application had to wait for the disk operations to complete, in milliseconds?*

Although, Linux kernel provides some statistics per process on IO (`/proc/<PID>/io`), I didn't find any way to get a cumulative wait time of a running (of completed) process.

CPU time is provided over `*rusage` structure of `wait4()` or `getrusage()` functions, but there is no IO wait time.

IO wait time as shown in top is not helpful, because it is calculated as a rate over period of time (*% = IOwait_time / Idle_Time over last 5 seconds*). Based on this information it is not possible to reliably calculate cumulative IO wait time of process over the lifetime of the process.

I cannot do any heavy user space profiling, since it will slow down the application. In the best case I'd like to collect total IO wait time of the process at the termination of the child process.

**From answers and comments:**

@emmrk provides a hint on checking per process statistics resource `/proc/<pid>/stat` process statistics interface. Unfortunately, this resource (in contrast to system-wide `/proc/stat`) does not provide IO wait counter.

@gavv: nice method of trapping the process just before exit is discussed:
[Extract all statistic of a process from /proc just before the process exit (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763987/extract-all-statistic-of-a-process-from-proc-just-before-the-process-exit-linu)

@Gaius [mentions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275449/duration-of-proc-pid-stat) that he is still able to read `/proc/<pid>/stat` even shortly after the process exit.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `man procfs`, the per-process `/proc/stat` entry:

```
         iowait (since Linux 2.5.41)
            (5) Time waiting for I/O to complete.
```

**EDIT:**

Depending on the accuracy you want to achieve, "practical" ways to get the value range from running a background script to `cat /proc/pid/stat` every `n` secs to using `kprobes` to trap `sys_exit` and read `/proc/pid/stat` while preventing the process from exiting.

The `kprobe` method may make your system unwieldy (since many processes won't be able to exit), so one more approach would be to hook up a function responsible for displaying stats through the `/proc/` fs. The related code is at `/fs/proc/stat.c` in the kernel source.

Comment: Thank you very much @emmrk for the useful hint! Could you possible extend the answer with the following information: what would be a practical way to collect the final value of this iowait variable? User Gaius in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275449/duration-of-proc-pid-stat)  suggests reading /proc entry after collecting process state with wait() call, but is it guaranteed to work? The is no explicit promise to keep the /proc/[pid] after process exit.

Comment: Activating the ["stop-on-exit" tracing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763987/extract-all-statistic-of-a-process-from-proc-just-before-the-process-exit-linu) on process may be a fitting answer, but what would be the overhead if it is activated on many processes?

Comment: the answer is still a bit fuzzy. I hoped that from the context of the question was clear, that I need a C API for collecting the IO wait time, not a shell script or a profiling tool. I am also not interested in an intermediate, obtained through polling, result but in the final state of the IO wait time counter. Let me know if I shall adjust the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @AntonGolubev it was not obvious at all. `kprobes` are not _strictly_ profiling. If you want C APIs, there are none - but you could just use the same approach that is shown in the `/fs/proc/stat.c` where the `iowait` is calculated.

Comment: I have just realized that a per-process version of /proc/<pid>/stat file does not include information about process IO wait time, as /proc/stat does. Do I miss something?

Comment: Ping @emmrk, forgot to include your tag in my previous comment. Please check it and say that you think.